Is this true? $\alpha\in$ Prime Ideal $P$ if and only if $\alpha r\in P$ for all $r\in R$.
Claim. Let $P\subset \text{commutative rng}\ R$ denote some arbitrary prime ideal. Then $\alpha\in P$ if and only if $\alpha r\in P$ for all $r\in R$.
Proof. If $\alpha\in P$, then by definition of ideals, it follows that $\alpha r\in P$ for all $r\in R$. Conversely, suppose we choose $\alpha\in R$ such that $\alpha r\in P$ for all $r\in R$. If we assume $\alpha\notin P$, then $\alpha r\in P$ implies $r\in P$ by definition of prime ideal. But since this'll hold for all $r\in R$, it follows that $P=R$. With this contradiction, we may conclude $\alpha\in P.\square$
Everything here seems alright...unless I'm missing something? Any help is appreciated. Not asking for much, just simple confirmation. Thank you!

Edit: At the request of a member in the community, I clarify that the point in my proof which I'm questionable on is with regards toward the conclusion. From what I've searched online, I struggle to find any sources backing my conclusion. However, everything in my proof seems pretty solid...maybe one point in the proof which may be of particular concern would be whether prime ideals are well-defined over commutative rngs? I assume identity isn't necessary, though almost all sources seem to define rings as having identity by definition.

If your ring is unital, then clearly if $\alpha r \in P$ for all $r \in R$, then certainly also $\alpha = \alpha \cdot 1 \in P$, without even using that $P$ is prime

@MikeDaas Good point. (p.s. Just for the sake of clarifying, I have since edited my initial post to specify I'm interested solely in the instance where $R$ is a commutative rng.)

For a solution-verification question to be on topic you must specify precisely which step in the proof you question, and why so. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

@BillDubuque Thank you for your comment. I have since updated the post as to address your remarks.

Your edit does not fix the problem. You need to identify a specific step in the proof which you doubt, and explain why you doubt it. Hover over the solution-verification tag to see its definition.

If $\alpha\notin P$ where $P$ is prime, then $\alpha\cdot \alpha\notin P$.

@BillDubuque my bad. I’ll fix it tomorrow morning.

@Asigan Could you clarify your point? I’m a little lost admittedly. I see that it’s true, but I’m struggling to see how it relates to the proof/statement…

@JAG131 This proves "$\alpha r\in P$ for all $r$ implies $\alpha\in P$" by proving the converse-negation statement: if $\alpha\notin P$, then exists $r\in P$ (i.e. $r=\alpha$) s.t. $ar\notin P$.
